# Find z^3 give a defined function

Tags: functions

I'm wondering where I should start..? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKYWb.png) << link

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please take the time to write out your question. Here is a [helpful formatting reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z^2(x,y)=(xy^3,y^4)$$

And then
$$z^3(x,y)=(xy^7,y^8)$$